# Can't count records in PHP result set hitting a SQL database?

Tags: php, sql

I have a PHP application which needs to query a Microsoft SQL database. That's easy enough, but I'm having trouble getting a "num_rows" from the result set ($rs)...here's my code, and some things I have tried - any help appreciated!

```
    $conn = new COM ("ADODB.Connection")or die("Cannot start ADO");
    $connStr = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=SQLServerIP;UID=UserID;PWD=MyPassword;DATABASE=MyDatabase";
    $conn->open($connStr); 
    $rs = $conn->execute($q);

    //Tried this: - gives error
    $num = $rs->field_count;

    //And this: - gives error
    $num = $rs->num_rows;

    //Any Ideas out there?
```

I know $rs holds the data, because I can successfully pull the data out with:

```
    echo $rs->Fields('Column1');
    echo $rs->Fields('Column2');
```

Comment: I doubt you can use `num_rows` with the MSSQL API. Here http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-num-rows.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-num-rows.php and RTM http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mssql.php

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the right API. Try `$rs->Fields->Count()`. Refer to http://php.net/manual/en/class.com.php as you are using the `Com` class to access the database.

Comment: This works and does not cause an error, but it's not coming back with the correct record count - that's weird....

Comment: Oh! this returns how many fields you have in the record set, NOT the number or rows in the set....that won't help me.

Answer (score 0):

try this I think it may help you

```
int mssql_num_rows ( resource $result )

mssql_num_rows() // returns the number of rows in a result set.
```

and here is the documentation's link for any extra info you need [enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-num-rows.php)

Comment: I already gave them that in a "comment". Had I known, I'd of put mine in as one.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice your comment,

Comment: I appreciate the honesty. Now let's see what the OP thinks/says ;-)

Comment: mssql_num_rows() nor mysql_num_rows() nor mssqli_num_rows() works...Call to undefined function mssql_num_rows()

Answer (score 0):

If that is the full snippet of your code, it looks like you are missing your actual SQL query.

See the line: `$rs = $conn->execute($q);`

Presumably, `$q` should be your sql query you are executing

So above your $rs, are we just missing some `$q = SELECT * FROM foo;` ?